# rabbitmq-server start up error at application_master.erl, line 138

Tags: rabbitmq

rabbitmq-server start up error,who can explain this message.

```
    =CRASH REPORT==== 16-Jun-2017::15:28:12 ===
          crasher:
            initial call: application_master:init/4
            pid: <0.154.0>
            registered_name: []
            exception exit: {bad_return,
                             {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
                              {'EXIT',
                               {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
                                {boot_step,recovery,
                                 {badmatch,
                                  {error,
                                   {{{function_clause,
                                      [{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,
                                        [{no_pub,no_del,ack,'...'},
                                         {{'...'},no_del,'...'}],
                                        []},
                                       {rabbit_queue_index,
                                        '-journal_minus_segment/2-fun-0-',4,[]},
                                       {array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{'...'},{'...'}]},
                                       {array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{'...'},{'...'}]},
                                       {rabbit_queue_index,
                                        '-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[]},
                                       {lists,map,2,[{'...'},{'...'},'...']},
                                       {rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[]},
                                       {rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[]}]},
                                     {gen_server2,call,[<0.216.0>,out,infinity]}},
                                    {child,undefined,msg_store_persistent,
                                     {rabbit_msg_store,start_link,
                                      [msg_store_persistent,"/srv/r...",[],
                                       {#Fun<rabbit_queue_index.2.60982745>,
                                        {start,'...'}}]},
                                     transient,4294967295,worker,
                                     [rabbit_msg_store]}}}}}}}}}
              in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 138)
            ancestors: [<0.153.0>]
            messages: [{'EXIT',<0.155.0>,normal}]
            links: [<0.153.0>,<0.7.0>]
            dictionary: []
```

trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 121393
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 6273
  neighbours:

We'd like to understand what this crash report means.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend asking questions like these on the [RabbitMQ Users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users). You did not provide many details, such as RabbitMQ server version, OS version, environment, configuration, etc etc. A stack trace is rarely enough to diagnose or reproduce a problem.

Based on the stack trace, it looks as though a directory whose name starts with `/srv/r...` may be missing or not have expected data in it.